# Find values in a map that ARE NOT in a list of pojos

Tags: java, java-stream

In my REST api, I'm accepting a map that looks like this -

`Map<String, Object> newSettings`-

```
{
  "showGrantsInGrid": false,
  "isPrimeUser": true,
  "hasRegistered": true
}
```

I need to compare those settings to an existing list of settings. That List looks like this -

`List<Setting> currentSettings` -

```java
[
  {
    "settingName": "showGrantsInGrid",
    "settingValue": "false",
  },
  {
    "settingName": "isPrimeUser",
    "settingValue": "true",
  }
]
```

This is what a Setting object looks like -

```java
public class Setting {
    private String settingName;

    private String settingValue;

    // getters and setters ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to find the entries that are in the map that was sent to the REST api that ARE NOT in the List of Settings. In the above example, that should be "hasRegistered".

Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Set<String> settingNames = currentSettings.stream()
          .map(Setting::getSettingName)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

then

```
newSettings.keySet().stream()
           .filter(key->!settingNames.contains(key))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

By one step:

```
currentSettings.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                    .collectingAndThen(Collectors
                                    .mapping(Setting::getSettingName, Collectors.toSet()),
                         settingName -> newSettings.keySet().stream()
                              .filter(key -> !settingName.contains(key))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
            );
```

Note: I'm not sure about its performance compared with the previous one.

Comment: Yeah. This is it. I was just about to answer my own question before you posted this. Essentially you have to flatten the original List, so it only contains keys, OR the way I just did it, create a flat map (instead of the list) with each k,v pair in it, then use contains on it. Thank you.

Comment: In the implementation you can notice `downstream.finisher().andThen(finisher)` about the execution of the latter. But to match the syntax, I believe `currentSettings.stream()
                .map(Setting::getSettingName)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(),
                        settingName -> newSettings.keySet().stream()
                                .filter(key -> !settingName.contains(key))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        )
                );` could just be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get all of the keys of newSettings with:

```
    List<String> newOnes = new ArrayList<>(); 

    Set<String> keys = newSettings.keySet();
    for (String key: keys) {
        // then, search through the list to see if it contains that name
        boolean present = false;
        for (Setting setting : currentSettings) {
             if (setting.getSettingName().equals(key)) {
                 present = true;
                 break;
             }
}
        if (!present) 
            newOnes.add(key);


    }
```

Comment: Did you mean newSettings.keySet? If I do that, I end up with [isPrimeUser, hasRegistered, hasRegistered]

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry! Just fixed it!

Comment: Unfortunately if I do that, I still get  [isPrimeUser, hasRegistered, hasRegistered] instead of just the one value "hasRegistered"

Comment: Ok. I put a bracket in the wrong place. Try again now. It's working for me. Sorry about that